# Scipy minimize name 'init_weigths' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Anyone knows why i get this undefined error on the minimize function ?
The variable init_weights in an array of float defined and filled before callin minimize function. However it doesnt seems to read it

```
def port_ret(weights):
    return ret.dot(weights.T).mean() * 252
# calculate annualized portfolio volatility (based on weights)

def port_vol(weights):
    return ret.dot(weights.T).std() * np.sqrt(252)


# define function to be minimized (sco only supports minimize, not maximize)
# -> maximize sharpe ratio == minimize sharpe ratio * (-1)
def min_func_sharpe(weights):
    return ((rf - port_ret(weights)) / port_vol(weights)) * -1  # sharpe ratio *


num_stocks = float(len(stocks.columns))
num_stock = len(stocks.columns)
init_weights = []
ueight = float(1/num_stocks)

for i in range(num_stock):
    init_weights.append(ueight)


# bounds: all weights shall be between 0 and 1 -> can be changed
bnds = tuple((0, 1) for i in range(num_stock))

# constraint: weights must sum up to 1 -> sum of weights - 1 = 0
cons = ({"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})

# run optimization based on function to be minimized, starting with equal weights and based on respective bounds and constraints
opts = minimize(fun=min_func_sharpe, x0=init_weigths, method="SLSQP",
                bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

Answer (score 0):

`eweights = np.array(init_weights)`

I had to transform the normal array in a numpy array before passing it to minimize